# Cannot automatically add event to Google Calendar

Tags: java, android, google-calendar-api

I have a problem with my TotalCalendar class. In this class I'm adding every events ( for example: 20 events ) to my own calendar. I should add this events to Google Calendar, but stil it's adding to device calendar. How can I change it? When I put single event to calendar, I can choose kind of calendar, but in this situation, I can't.

```
public class TotalCalendar {
    Context mContext;
    Intent mIntent;

    public TotalCalendar(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public boolean insert(String dzien, String miesiac, String lokacja, String tytul, String opis, String godziny) {

        int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
        Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        int currentMonth = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH);

        if((Miesiac(miesiac) == 0) && (currentMonth == 11)  )
        {
            year++;
        }

        int hh1 = 0;
        int mm1 = 0;
        int hh2 = 0;
        int mm2 = 0;

        if(isNumeric(getHH1(godziny)) && isNumeric(getMM2(godziny)))
        {
            Log.d("debug","numeric");
            hh1 = Integer.valueOf(getHH1(godziny)).intValue();
            mm1 = Integer.valueOf(getMM1(godziny)).intValue();
            hh2 = Integer.valueOf(getHH2(godziny)).intValue();
            mm2 = Integer.valueOf(getMM2(godziny)).intValue();
        }
        else
        {
            hh1 = 0;
            mm1 = 0;
            hh2 = 0;
            mm2 = 0;
        }

        beginTime.set(year, Miesiac(miesiac), Integer.valueOf(dzien).intValue(), hh1, mm1);
        endTime.set(year, Miesiac(miesiac), Integer.valueOf(dzien).intValue(), hh2, mm2);
        Log.d("debug", "Begin time: " + Miesiac(miesiac) + " " + Integer.valueOf(dzien));

        long startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
        long endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();


        ContentResolver cr = mContext.getContentResolver();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();

        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endMillis);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE,tytul);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION,opis);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID,1);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE,tz.getID());
        Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI,values);


        Uri.Builder builder = CalendarContract.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();
        builder.appendPath("time");
        ContentUris.appendId(builder, startMillis);

        this.mIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(builder.build());
        mIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        mContext.startActivity(mIntent);

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: What's the actual question? Your code adds new events to the calendar having the `CALENDAR_ID` `1` (which happens to be the "device" calendar on some devices). Just insert the calendar id of your Google calendar instead. Or do you want to know how to find the id of the Google calendar Also be aware that not every user might have a Google calendar.

Comment: Exactly! In my dreams, I will have an option dialog, and can choose which calendar want I to use.